# ORA-00904 is coming while executing this query select emp, hiredate from emp where year(hiredate)>80;

Tags: oracle11g

ORA-00904 error is coming while using select emp, hiredate from emp where year(hiredate)>80;  query.

Comment: Which identifier is it complaining about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `year()` function in Oracle. Perhaps you want [the`extract()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm):

```
select emp, hiredate from emp
where extract(year from hiredate) > 80;
```

Although you're rather unlikely to have emloyees hired *before* year 80 - in the first century AD/CE - so that will find everyone, and really you want:

```
select emp, hiredate from emp
where extract(year from hiredate) > 1980;
```

Unless you add a function-based index that will have to check the value from every row; to use an existing index on that column you could do:

```
select emp, hiredate from emp
where hiredate >= date '1981-01-01';
```

Comment: Yes extract function is working, thanks for the information